# how to get count of rating in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model like that

```
class UserRating(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    rate = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I rate this in a range of 1 to 4 where 4 is excellent, 3 is very good, 2 is good, 1 is bad
and I should get the count of rating according to the number given by user. I am using `SerializerMethodField` like that is

```
def get_excellent(self, obj):
    return models.UserRating.objects.filter(rate=4, status=True).count()


def get_very_good(self, obj):
    return models.UserRating.objects.filter(rate=3, status=True).count()


def get_good(self, obj):
    return models.UserRating.objects.filter(rate=2, status=True).count()

def get_bad(self, obj):
    return models.UserRating.objects.filter(rate=1, status=True).count()
```

but it is bad idea to do this because it goes to the db the four times. I am looking for better way of doing this. Is there any help please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to use annotations or a raw query for better performance. And make sure your fields are indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firstly its better to use choices in your model if your values is predefined

```py
class UserRating(models.Model):
    RATE_CHOICES = (
        (4, "excellent"),
        (3, "very good"),
        (2, "good"),
        (1, "bad"),
    )
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    rate = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=RATE_CHOICES)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and your query to get count of ratings is this:

```py
from django.db.models import Count

rate_count_dict = UserRating.objects.values('rate').annotate(rate_count=Count('rate'))
```

you can simply assign `rate_count_dict` to your serializer's context and access it in your serializer